# Инициализация UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol, property

Есть `public DataGridView DataGridView { get; set; }` свойство в моем UserControl.
Оно может устанавливаться в DesignMode. После этого мне необходимо инициализировать его. Однако(если установить это свойство из DesignMode), если делать это в конструкторе или onLoad, то данное свойство все еще ссылается на null.
В какой момент проводить инициализацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается этот вопрос при помощи реализации ISupportInitialize. В методе EndInit можно обращаться ко всем полям. В нем мой DataGridView уже будет инициализирован.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы добавляли это свойство не через дизайнер форм, то его инициализации не будет в сгенерированном методе InitializeComponent. В этом случае его нужно самостоятельно проинициализировать, например, в конструкторе:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public DataGridView DataGridView { get; set; }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataGridView = new DataGridView();
        // прочая инициализация
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, у меня немного другая ситуация. DataGridView находится на форме а не в UserControl'e. И я в дизайнере указываю для моего UserControl это свойство например dgvClients. Но на форме сначала инициализируется мой компонент и ему передается dgvCleints == null.

Comment: Вы в дизайнере добавляете на форму и DataGridView и UserControl?

Comment: Да, и для UserControl указываю DataGridView

Comment: Попробуйте поменять местами инициализацию DataGridView и UserControl в сгенерированном файле. Так, чтобы dataGrid был выше, чем control.

Comment: Хах, да. Я думаю это решит проблему, но это же будет костылем, не так ли?

Comment: Не думаю, что это костыль. Это то же самое, что перетащить сначала grid на форму, а потом control. На мой взгляд, бОльшая проблема в том, что у UserControl'а устанавливается значение свойства-контрола извне.

Comment: Как раз это и будет костылем. А если вы делаете компонент не разовый для себя, а на продажу. Вы будете в инструкции по использованию писать, чтоб пользователь сначала перетащил DataGridView на форму, а уже потом Ваш контрол?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22927/discussion-between-ism-and-vlad).